# Multi OR in query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it a bad idea to keep word translations for two languages ​​in one table? The table structure looks like this: **id (char) lang1(char) lang2(char)**

I choose the translation for the selected language in this way:

```
    $words = ['content_title_log_in', 'content_title_register_account', 'content_title_contact'];

$q = 'SELECT lang1 FROM language WHERE ';
foreach ($words as $key => $value) {

    if($key == 0)
        $q .= 'id='.$value;
    else
        $q .= ' OR id='.$value;

}
```

And I have a query.
Will doing such an OR operator 100 times in one query will not slow down the database? Is this a good practice?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: "what if I need to add another language?"

Comment: Doing 100 `OR` clauses is probably a bad plan. That's why there's the [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function. Even better, why can't you express this as a `JOIN` between table A containing that list of words and table B containing the translations?

Comment: as @tadman says, you need `IN()`... something like that: `'select ... from ... where id in('. implode(',',$words) .')';`